# Variable not defined error even if it's defined

Tags: python

I've been trying to learn Python and created a little program that asks for a budget and recommends instruments I can't figure out how to solve this problem saying "NameError: name 'instrument is not defined". I am almost sure it happens because I've put instrument_choice function there, without it, it was working.

Here's my code:

```
list1 = ["Piano", "Keys"]
list2 = ["Piano", "Keys", "Bass", "Plucks", "Pads", "Guitar"]
list3 = ["Bass"]
list4 = ["Guitar", "Bass"]
list5 = ["Synth"]

print("Hi! Welcome to VST instrument selector.")

def instrument_choice():
    instrument = input("Which instrument do you want to get? (Keys, Bass, etc.) ").capitalize()

    while True:
        if not (instrument in list2) and (instrument != "!help"):
            print("This instrument type is not valid. Try again. For the list of instruments, type !help.")
            instrument_choice()
        if instrument in list2:
            break
        if instrument == "!help":
            print("""Available instruments types are Piano, Keys, Bass, Plucks, Pads & Guitar.
Also you need to only write numbers while writing your budget do not type '300 USD' or '300 dollars'. Just type '300'.""")
            instrument_choice()
            break

instrument_choice()

def nobudget():
    while True:
        try:
            budget = int(input("What's your budget? (in $) "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please use digits.")
            continue
        else:
            break

    if (budget < 169):
        print("There is no plugin available for this budget. Try to raise your budget.")
        while True:
            nobudget()
            break
    if (instrument in list2) and (budget >= 499):
        print("You can get Spectrasonic Omnisphere 2, it's $499!")
    if (instrument in list4) and (budget >= 299):
        print("You can get Spectrasonic Trillian, it's $299!")
    if (instrument in list1) and (budget >= 169):
        print("You can get Addictive Keys 2, it's $169!")
    if (instrument in list1) and (budget >= 399):
        print("You can get Spectrasonics Keyscape, it's $399!")
    if (instrument in list1) and (budget >= 199):
        print("You can get Lounge Lizard EP-4, it's $199!")
    if (instrument in list5) and (budget >= 189):
        print("You can get Xfer Serum, it's $189!")
    if (instrument in list3) and (budget >= 299):
        print("You can get MODO Bass, it's $299! It also has a lite version, MODO Bass SE for $149!")

nobudget()
```

Comment: The variable name ``instrument`` is only available in the method ``instrument_choice`` - it is a **local** variable and cannot be access outside of that method. You should read about ``scopes``.

Comment: the object `instrument` defined in `instrument_choice` is local to the method, the other method don't have access to it,

Comment: For learning purposes, have a look at scope and the [LEGB](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/) rule to understand how variables etc. can be accessed in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to solve:
(1) Add 'instrument' to your global variable list:

```
list1 = ["Piano", "Keys"]
list2 = ["Piano", "Keys", "Bass", "Plucks", "Pads", "Guitar"]
list3 = ["Bass"]
list4 = ["Guitar", "Bass"]
list5 = ["Synth"]
instrument = ''
```

(2) in both the functions (below 'def' line) add

```
global instrument
```

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned instrument is declared within a function, thus it does not exist outside of that function.
To fix it you need to add the variable outside of the function and refer to it as global in the function. This way it is distributed.

I have amended your code:

```
list1 = ["Piano", "Keys"]
list2 = ["Piano", "Keys", "Bass", "Plucks", "Pads", "Guitar"]
list3 = ["Bass"]
list4 = ["Guitar", "Bass"]
list5 = ["Synth"]

print("Hi! Welcome to VST instrument selector.")
instrument = ''
def instrument_choice():
    global instrument
    instrument = input("Which instrument do you want to get? (Keys, Bass, etc.) ").capitalize()

    while True:
        if not (instrument in list2) and (instrument != "!help"):
            print("This instrument type is not valid. Try again. For the list of instruments, type !help.")
            instrument_choice()
        if instrument in list2:
            break
        if instrument == "!help":
            print("""Available instruments types are Piano, Keys, Bass, Plucks, Pads & Guitar.
Also you need to only write numbers while writing your budget do not type '300 USD' or '300 dollars'. Just type '300'.""")
            instrument_choice()
            break

instrument_choice()

def nobudget():
    global instrument
    while True:
        try:
            budget = int(input("What's your budget? (in $) "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please use digits.")
            continue
        else:
            break

    if (budget < 169):
        print("There is no plugin available for this budget. Try to raise your budget.")
        while True:
            nobudget()
            break
    if (instrument in list2) and (budget >= 499):
        print("You can get Spectrasonic Omnisphere 2, it's $499!")
    if (instrument in list4) and (budget >= 299):
        print("You can get Spectrasonic Trillian, it's $299!")
    if (instrument in list1) and (budget >= 169):
        print("You can get Addictive Keys 2, it's $169!")
    if (instrument in list1) and (budget >= 399):
        print("You can get Spectrasonics Keyscape, it's $399!")
    if (instrument in list1) and (budget >= 199):
        print("You can get Lounge Lizard EP-4, it's $199!")
    if (instrument in list5) and (budget >= 189):
        print("You can get Xfer Serum, it's $189!")
    if (instrument in list3) and (budget >= 299):
        print("You can get MODO Bass, it's $299! It also has a lite version, MODO Bass SE for $149!")

nobudget()
```

Answer (score 0):

`instrument` is a local variable which means that it is only accessible in the `instrument_choice` function. If you want to use it in the `nobudget` function, you need to declare it globally.

This works for me:

```
list1 = ["Piano", "Keys"]
list2 = ["Piano", "Keys", "Bass", "Plucks", "Pads", "Guitar"]
list3 = ["Bass"]
list4 = ["Guitar", "Bass"]
list5 = ["Synth"]

print("Hi! Welcome to VST instrument selector.")


def instrument_choice():
    instrument = input(
        "Which instrument do you want to get? (Keys, Bass, etc.) ").capitalize()

    while True:
        if not (instrument in list2) and (instrument != "!help"):
            print(
                "This instrument type is not valid. Try again. For the list of instruments, type !help.")
            instrument_choice()
        if instrument in list2:
            break
        if instrument == "!help":
            print("""Available instruments types are Piano, Keys, Bass, Plucks, Pads & Guitar.
Also you need to only write numbers while writing your budget do not type '300 USD' or '300 dollars'. Just type '300'.""")
            instrument_choice()
            break
    
    return instrument # HERE


instrument = instrument_choice() # HERE


def nobudget(instrument): # HERE
    while True:
        try:
            budget = int(input("What's your budget? (in $) "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please use digits.")
            continue
        else:
            break

    if (budget < 169):
        print("There is no plugin available for this budget. Try to raise your budget.")
        while True:
            nobudget()
            break
    if (instrument in list2) and (budget >= 499):
        print("You can get Spectrasonic Omnisphere 2, it's $499!")
    if (instrument in list4) and (budget >= 299):
        print("You can get Spectrasonic Trillian, it's $299!")
    if (instrument in list1) and (budget >= 169):
        print("You can get Addictive Keys 2, it's $169!")
    if (instrument in list1) and (budget >= 399):
        print("You can get Spectrasonics Keyscape, it's $399!")
    if (instrument in list1) and (budget >= 199):
        print("You can get Lounge Lizard EP-4, it's $199!")
    if (instrument in list5) and (budget >= 189):
        print("You can get Xfer Serum, it's $189!")
    if (instrument in list3) and (budget >= 299):
        print("You can get MODO Bass, it's $299! It also has a lite version, MODO Bass SE for $149!")


nobudget(instrument) # HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the small problems, passing `list2` to the function as an argument, I don't recommend using instrument as a `global variable` and your first function should return the instrument selected and store it in a variable to then use it in your next function, with this you don't have to change your code that much

```
list1 = ["Piano", "Keys"]
list2 = ["Piano", "Keys", "Bass", "Plucks", "Pads", "Guitar"]
list3 = ["Bass"]
list4 = ["Guitar", "Bass"]
list5 = ["Synth"]

print("Hi! Welcome to VST instrument selector.")

def instrument_choice(list2):
    instrument = input("Which instrument do you want to get? (Keys, Bass, etc.) ").capitalize()

    while True:
        if not (instrument in list2) and (instrument != "!help"):
            print("This instrument type is not valid. Try again. For the list of instruments, type !help.")
            instrument_choice(list2)
        if instrument in list2:
            return instrument #We return the instrument if everything is OK.
            break
        if instrument == "!help":
            print("""Available instruments types are Piano, Keys, Bass, Plucks, Pads & Guitar.
Also you need to only write numbers while writing your budget do not type '300 USD' or '300 dollars'. Just type '300'.""")
            instrument_choice(list2)
            break
#Store the instrument in a variable
inst = instrument_choice(list2)

def nobudget(instrument): #Pass the instrument to the function
    while True:
        try:
            budget = int(input("What's your budget? (in $) "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please use digits.")
            continue
        else:
            break
    if (budget < 169):
        print("There is no plugin available for this budget. Try to raise your budget.")
        while True:
            nobudget()
            break
    if (instrument in list2) and (budget >= 499):
        print("You can get Spectrasonic Omnisphere 2, it's $499!")
    if (instrument in list4) and (budget >= 299):
        print("You can get Spectrasonic Trillian, it's $299!")
    if (instrument in list1) and (budget >= 169):
        print("You can get Addictive Keys 2, it's $169!")
    if (instrument in list1) and (budget >= 399):
        print("You can get Spectrasonics Keyscape, it's $399!")
    if (instrument in list1) and (budget >= 199):
        print("You can get Lounge Lizard EP-4, it's $199!")
    if (instrument in list5) and (budget >= 189):
        print("You can get Xfer Serum, it's $189!")
    if (instrument in list3) and (budget >= 299):
        print("You can get MODO Bass, it's $299! It also has a lite version, MODO Bass SE for $149!")


nobudget(inst) # HERE
```